# Where does, Carp library in Perl, print logs when run from crontab

Tags: linux, perl, shell, io, cron

I have a Perl script that uses Carp (carp croak) to print info and errors.
When run directly I can see the output on console. But when I am running the script as cronjob I dont know where the messages are going.

Already checked in /var/log/messages  /var/log/cron . Not found

Please help.

Comment: Have a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207/where-are-cron-errors-logged

Comment: I did go through that before but I could not find the logs at mentioned locations in there... Like I have told above.... Also the link talks about directing output to some file or stream. I want to know where it goes by default.

Comment: Can you add your crontab file to the question? Also, what version of *nix are you using? Perhaps your `/etc/crontab` file. Anything to help diagnose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`man cron`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cron):

> When executing commands, any output is mailed to the owner of the
>   crontab (or to the user named in the MAILTO environment variable in
>   the crontab, if such exists). Job output can also be sent to syslog by
>   using the **-s** option.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should redirect the stdout in your cronjob.